# Links beginning with a capital letter are hidden when post is submitted

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

Links written with the first character as a capital, e.g.

```
Http://stackoverflow.com
```

do not appear in a post, although they are shown in the preview. Here is a link that becomes invisible after submitting the post:

Comment: Http://comments.are.unaffected.example.com

Comment: It also happens in part of the domain if you read the information presented you'll see that its a bigger issue than just the scheme.

Comment: Are protocols actually case-sensitive ? I'm pretty sure they aren't (just like hostnames) in which case "Http" should just be converted to "http" on submission.

Comment: The scheme isn't and the domain shouldn't be however the path can be interpreted with case sensitivity so that should be left alone obviously.

Comment: Since it is invisible, wouldn't it be possible to hide spam this way? If so I would see it as a problem.

Comment: @bummi  Since it's "invisible" I don't see how it could be a problem. "to hide spam this way" *Hidden* spam is not really a big problem.

Comment: @James I was thinking about Google e.g., not sure what can be used for link popularity, since preview and content seem to be scanned. My knowledge here is poor, it was an apprehension.

Comment: @bummi But where does Google get "invisible" and "hidden" links from? At worst there may be something in the edit history. Although, Spam is dealt with quite strictly, so it would be removed, along with the user. And all links are no-follow anyway. I could be wrong, I just don't know of a scenario where this would be an issue.

Comment: @bummi Google can't see these "invisible" links in posts, because if you actually look at the HTML, you'll see they aren't even there. It's not that they're present but hidden, they just aren't generated in the HTML output for the post.

Comment: About the spam, even though it's not visible in the html, if the googlebot can follow links (and yes, it can) it can also find the spam under the edit link. So, there you have it.

Comment: Turns out that you can't use this to circumvent the minimum length restriction on the main site. http://i.stack.imgur.com/n9jq6.png

Comment: Well then that's a positive thing!

Comment: data query to help find such potential invisible links: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/722474/find-invisible-links

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Nice finding that bug.

For proof that it really is a bug, refer to [RFC 3986, section 3.1 Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

> Although schemes are case-
> insensitive, the canonical form is lowercase and documents that
> specify schemes must do so with lowercase letters.  An implementation
> should accept uppercase letters as equivalent to lowercase in scheme
> names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http") for the sake of
> robustness but should only produce lowercase scheme names for
> consistency.

The comment-handling seems to work right.

Comment: When all else fails refer to the request for comments :-D

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it's a "bug" here. If the way it is currently handled  is how it was *decided* to be handled, then it is status-bydesign. Of course, that's not saying the "design" shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @James: why would this be "by design"? It being a straight-out *bug* is far more likely, per [Hanlon's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor).

Comment: @Jongware I don't know, I don't have access to the site's back end code or previous dev discussions and decisions. That's why I said "doesn't necessarily" and "**If** the way it is currently handled..."

Comment: @James "I've got an idea," said one of the developers. "What if capitalized URLs, instead of being treated as either links *or* plain-text, were made *ENTIRELY INVISIBLE* instead?" "Okay," said the other developers. "We hereby intend that to be how things should work."

Comment: @Sneftel  Your sarcasm is based on speculation. You do not know whether that scenario is real or not, you just *think* it's not because it is the less likely one. "Less likely" is not conclusive.

Comment: @Sneftel James is correct. You're speculating.

Comment: @james Sufficiently less likely is conclusive, as no evidence is sufficient to make any claim more than sufficiently less likely.  Developers posting with exact statements is not conclusive: they could have hallucinated.  Sneftel's argument is robust: the design of "make them invisible" is pretty ridiculous.  As a guess (and this is a guess, not conclusive), they have a "check URLs for attacks, and if we don't read the URL as clean, we hide it", and the code for the check doesn't admit the possibility of MiXeD CaSe HtTp.

Comment: StackExchange markdown seems to [break unexpectedly with URLs in posts quite often, then work perfectly well in comments](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2556/2242)...

Comment: @Yakk "*The design of 'make them invisible' is pretty ridiculous*" Is it? So, how they should have handled it? And presuming they "did not want them to be seen"...

Answer (score 41):

I tested this in the [MSE Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245059/203888) first, but now that I can replicate it, it looks like any capital letter in the protocol section of a link created by specifying a bare URL in Markdown results in this behavior - disappearance of the link.

Here's a copy of what I tested, in case the sandbox answer is changed/updated.

---

Testing normal:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

http://stackoverflow.com

---

Testing Http

```
Http://stackoverflow.com
```

---

Testing Https

```
Https://stackoverflow.com
```

---

Testing Ftp

```
Ftp://example.com
```

---

Testing a nonexistent protocol

```
DoesNotExist://example.com
```

DoesNotExist://example.com

---

Testing ALL CAPS:

```
HTTP://example.com
```

---

Testing rEVERSE cAPITALIZATION:

```
hTTP://www.example.com
```

---

Testing capital only in Domain:

```
http://Www.example.com
```

http://Www.example.com

Comment: Good find!  Even more of a reason to fix

Comment: "DoesNotExist://example.com" +1 for thinking on that

Comment: You can get the preview right (i.e. with some links invisible) if you put your link between HTML brackets `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 8):

There are two highly upvoted answers here that state "yes it is a bug" and a couple of downvoted ones that say "don't fix it".

I would like to offer this answer in favor of the "let's fix it" camp - and maybe to get a taly. We will see from the up/down votes what the community thinks. Consider this intended as a counterpoint to answers that say "don't fix it".

When someone includes a link in their answer that would be valid if copy/pasted into the address bar of their browser, it is reasonable to assume they intend it to be used as a link. While I understand that the current "link validator" may trip over the capitalization, I would like to see a change to the engine that allows the link - whether formatted with a `[text](Http://link)` or directly as a `Http://link`. It would be a very simple matter to return the protocol string as all lower case - no harder than rendering it invisible, for instance.

I see three possible approaches.

1. Do nothing
2. Render every valid link as typed
3. Fix formatting of unconventionally cApItalized protocol strings

If you believe the current behavior is preferable, please downvote my answer. If you want either (2) or (3), indicate so by upvoting. A simple comment "prefer option 2" or "prefer option 3" would help (and that's exactly 15 characters...)

I don't buy the argument that "allowing unconventional capitalization will bring down the quality of the site". We have plenty of keen editors who will fix the occasionally mistyped protocol. My preference is for option 3 (but I can't upvote my own answer :-) )

Comment: prefer option 3

Comment: I'd like to point out that my answer is not saying "don't fix it" exactly.  I support making the text visible.  I am only against altering the link-rendering code to allow `Http` as a link.  This is an *added* feature that I think should not be built.

Comment: That said, I think it would be great if SE is willing to have the protocols be auto-lowercased.  It would fix all of the problems and save editors the time of correcting unconventional URLs.  +1

Comment: Definitely agree it needs to be fixed.

Comment: I never said don't fix it, anywhere, once, not even suggested it...

Comment: @James - you did say that it was not a simple fix, and that effort was not worth it for the infrequent occurrence: "Not for such a small issue with likely a tiny occurrence..".  I may have read more into that statement than you intended, and I apologize for misrepresenting you.

Comment: I said "So these would be new systems, and not really a simple resolve to this bug" And that was *specifically* in context of Jay's suggestion of all sorts of new system requirements, such as auto correct and scripts checking specifically for `http` etc. Again, I agree *something* should be done, just *what should be done* is the big question. And I stand by no-one knowing whether this is a bug or not other than devs, as per my new answer (FWIW). No need for apology, we're all just chewin' the fat ;)

Answer (score -1):

In response to comments, and now an answer in response to my saying not to fix it.
I have said throughout that I don't disagree it "could" be a bug, just that only the developers can confirm this.
I also agreed somewhere that non lowercase `http` simply *not rendering* is not practical or ideal at all.

### My entire point has been this:

The general consensus seems to be "This shouldn't be like this therefore it's a *bug*". And as it's allowed in the RFC Stack not allowing it is therefore a bug.

A bug is not "something which doesn't work how we believe it *should* work".
That's just something which could be "improved", including allowing mixed case `http` because the RFC states it's permissible.

A bug is *specifically* "something which doesn't work *how it was intended to work*".
If a script for users to login doesn't allow users to login, there is a bug.

Users arguing "*devs would not just allow non lowercase `http` to not render*" have not worked in a crazy/busy dev pit, "things" sometimes happen like this.

Perhaps it is a bug, and the devs shrugged their shoulders because it doesn't harm anything. Perhaps they already have it on a loooong todo list to sort one day.

Only *they* know *their* intentions etc.

---

---

### To allow mixed case or not

It can be argued that because an RFC states mixed case `http` is allowed, then a site such as Stack should allow it, given it's significant presence on the internet for technology based discussions etc.

However, *I* don't agree we should just because RFC states it's *allowed*.
I also see a good argument that Stack should set an example in having continuity in content, such as only allowing lower case `http`, and not having messy looking `hTtp` and other variants.

Profanities are a *valid* part of the English language, but they have no place on Stack.
Why ever not - **they are in the dictionary**, *so therefore Stack should allow them.*

No, Stack decides that even though profanities are a valid part of the language, it's offensive so they don't allow it.
Just as mixed case `http` is in the RFC, but it's messy and looks poor.

We can make choices, and not allowing mixed case `http` doesn't mean we're stating it is not correct, just the same as we're not stating profanities are not a part of the dictionary.
We're just making choices as to what we want to see on our site.

`http` is acceptable, and *looks better* than mixed case, so why not enforce all lowercase to be clean looking?

[Please don't argue that it's entirely different because profanities are offensive whereas mixed case http is not. Of course that's true, but the entire point is *both are **valid** yet we can choose not to allow them*.]

### What should be done about it

So, discussion on the main issue here, and that is currently *users text disappears without warning or notification*, which is not fair and is quite confusing.

I do agree that non lowercase `http` *simply not rendering* is not a good scenario. Users will wonder where their link went to, they might not even notice it.
And of course it could be the main part of the question or answer, and so they receive downvotes as a result of the Q or A being poor etc.

However, would you really be happy for posts around the site to look like this:
`HTtp://stackoverflow.com`
`hTtP://stackoverflow.com`
`htTP://stackoverflow.com`
+ others

Or, only ever allow:
`http://stackoverflow.com`

Personally, I think the mixed case ones look stupid, and Stack should promote clean looking URLs and have continuity throughout the site, not just conform to some RFC.

However, we do need to do something other than pretend the mixed case `http` didn't exist.

---

So, I think the best solution would be for non lowercase `http` to be automatically put in quoted text block.
Then the link is still there, users can see it's there but not rendering, and can edit the post to fix it.

Then we don't see `HtTp` in the site as genuine links, which looks stupid and ugly.

Comment: Clear and sensible answer.

Comment: And that is one of my main concerns.  The moment we allow `Http:...` as a link is the moment when all other (ugly) forms start slipping in simply because they "work in the browser".  There is something to be said for respecting consistency and convention.  Thanks for giving some examples of how bad bad can get.

Answer (score -10):

**TL;DR:**  We should make the text visible, but it should not be a link.  Instead, it should be plain text.

---

Apparently, the community feels very strongly that this is an issue worth fixing.  My original answer said that it wasn't much of a problem and that we should ignore the behavior for the sake of having correctly formed URLs in posts.  But after ~20 downvotes and a hoard of negative comments, I am willing to retract that opinion for the sake of the community.

**However**, I--and I'm sure quite a few others--still strongly believe that we should not treat `Http:` as if it were a properly formed protocol.  It is simply incorrect by convention and accepting it will only encourage people to use the incorrect form in posts.  Also, it opens the door for all other variations of the protocol such as `HTTP:`, `hTTp:`, etc.  While this is not *horrible*, it still brings down the quality of the posts on our site (and makes us look like we don't know what a protocol is ;)

Therefore, I offer a compromise:  we should change the behavior so that the text is visible in the post, but we should not make it a valid link.  Instead, it should be rendered as plain text.

In defense of this proposal, I have four points to make:

1. I refer you to [@rgettman's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280154/2555451) and how `DoesNotExist://example.com` renders as plain text in the post.  Just as `DoesNotExist:` is not treated as valid protocol, so `Http:` should be likewise ignored.
2. By making the `Http:` text visible, we stop people from including hidden spam in posts as well as circumventing the character limit for posts ([@MartinSmith's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280148/2555451) is a prime example of this last point).  At the same time, by not making it a valid link, we encourage users to edit `Http:` to the correct `http:` form so that their links work as intended.
3. This proposal does not interfere with the author's intent in any way by auto-correcting the links.  Instead, it posts *exactly* what the author types.  And if they want it to be a real link, all they need to do is edit `H` to `h`, which takes little more than a second.
4. I've said this before, but we cannot allow `Http:` as a valid protocol because then `hTTp:` and all other incorrect forms should likewise be allowed by the same logic.  And then, why not also allow people to omit the `http:` altogether and just post www.site.com or even just site.com?.  As you can see, there is really no end to this.  If we make more than one valid way to render links, then we will soon have dozens of ways to render links.

   Limiting users to just one correct form keeps things consistent and easy to manage.

As for comments allowing `Http:`, I do not think that that is a valid argument because comments are 2nd-class citizens. You can't really compare them with questions and answers. Just because comments allow incorrectly formed URLs does not mean we should transfer this behavior to the important posts. Also, typing comments is a very rapid action, which means typos are natural in comments. Questions and answers though should be written with care and quality.

In summary, I see this as being the best of both worlds.  We eliminate all the problems with the invisible text as well as prevent people from using `Http:` as if it were correct.

Comment: Great now your half way there, just a little more and we're good. You still don't seem to understand that no matter which case I type it in the functionality should not change.  Maybe if my text wasn't turned into a link automatically then this would not be an issue. Since its changed it needs to be changed correctly.

Comment: Eh, that's as far as I can go.  I can't accept `Http:` as a correctly written protocol.  It is simply incorrect.  And I don't see why the site should have to compensate for people thinking it is correct.  Making the text visible is fine, but treating `Http:...` as equal to `http:...` is a design flaw.  A bug if you will. ;)  It does not make the site more intuitive or user-friendly.  Instead, it trashes convention, allows ugly and incorrect URLs, and makes the code for rendering links all the more complex since we now have to account for *every* possible variation of every possible protocol.

Comment: You would have to account for all forms.  Allowing `Http:` but not say `HTTP:` is arbitrary.  Why is one incorrect form acceptable but not the other incorrect form?  But I respect your opinion.  Besides, it's not like you or I have any say over what happens anyways since only the SE devs themselves can make the final decision.  We'll just have to wait and see.  In the meantime, have a nice holiday season. :)

Comment: Again limited thinking on how to handle it. Right on. Thanks.  U too.

Comment: @iCodez At least you're thinking logically and with an open mind. Discussions should remain civil and *all* those involved should consider others' opinions with the potential of having one's mind changed, or just learning a new perspective. Not just beat down those who disagree, and upvote and grin with those who do agree. Sigh...

Comment: @James - I agree.  Sadly however, it seems that we are really outvoted in this.  The community's will is case-insensitive protocols, so that will probably be put into effect despite our arguments against it.  Oh well, we tried.  So much for following convention. :)

Comment: Not necessarily, it's up to Stack at the end of the day, whether they feel it's worthwhile, and should be done. There are many posts with hundreds and some thousands of up votes on MSE, yet nothing is done. I'm not against change, or improvement, as long as the proposed change is decent. And I disagree that just allowing all kinds of mixed case within `http` is acceptable, and nor do I care what any RFC states. I've yet to see any feasible solution - even Jay deleted his answer with a proposed idea...

Comment: The protocol scheme is [case-insensitive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280171/466862), so they **should work**

Comment: But `Http` _is_ a correctly formed protocol! The site has plenty of editors willing to fix typos when they are them - but the can't see the invisible link. I don't buy the argument that allowing legal links would bring down the quality of SE. There are more important things to worry about.

Comment: @Floris - `Http` is correct in the same sense that `hTTp` is.  Meaning, they will *work* if you happen to type them into a browser (browsers are often smart enough to lowercase it for you), but they are still incorrectly formed by convention.  I'd be fine if SO was willing to auto-lowercase `Http` like browsers do, but that interferes with the author's post too much.  So, I am against allowing `Http` as a link for the sake of having proper URLs.

Comment: @Floris - Otherwise, we'll have practically anything be a URL.  I mean, you are fine with `Http:...` but what about `hTTp:...` or `HTTp:` or even no protocol (`www.site.com` as I said in my post).  Do you see what I mean?  We cannot allow *just* `Http` and ignore all other forms because that is arbitrary.  If we allow one, we will sooner or later allow them all.

Comment: @iCodez - my suggestion is to allow "anything that is a valid link". I would argue that while you can omit `http://` in many address bars, that doesn't make it a valid link; but a server will respond correctly to the request `hTtP://...`. I argue that "if it is valid, allow it". If it bothers you that this is "ugly", then the simple tweak to take the (valid) protocol string and render it as all lower case would be a very simple piece of code. But I believe the current status is a bug, not a feature. That's just an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: @Floris - Well, that seems to be at the heart of this debate.  Jay and his supporters are arguing that the text not being a link is the bug while I and others are arguing that the text being invisible is the bug and it being made a link is an added feature that should not be implemented.  Thankfully, we all are at least agreed that there *is* a bug somewhere.  But like I said to Jay, no-one on this page has the power to give a final say in this.  We'll just have to wait for a decision from SE.  (Hopefully, they'll bring out a giant `http` and then all will be good ;-)

Comment: I think the bug is the text now showing when the protocol has unconventional capitalization. It makes no difference to me if it works with `Http` or not: **as long as the text doesn't go away**... Leaving `Http://www.example.com` as plain text is the best of both worlds. -1 for saying to do not fix when it's obvious that there is a bug.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - How do you come to that conclusion after reading my answer?  I'm curious because others have said the same thing.  I **do support** fixing the visibility bug.  My whole answer supports it.  I am only against making `Http` a link.

Comment: I can't seem to find where it is supporting the fix. Can you please enlighten me to fix my incorrect judgement?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - I said: *"Therefore, I offer a compromise: we should change the behavior so that the text is visible in the post, but we should not make it a valid link. Instead, it should be rendered as plain text."*  I want the `Http` text to be plain text and not a link.

Comment: The phrasing hides that line completely into the text. I recommend that you repeat it in other words at the bottom, but supporting the same idea. This would avoid confusions. I want to revert my downvote, but you have to edit the question before. A space or something is enough.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - There, I put it right at the top.  Geez, I hope that that is not the reason why I got all these downvotes, because people couldn't find my point. :/  Thanks for bringing that issue up.

Comment: You're welcome. I have reverted the vote. But look at the bright side: The downvotes here don't count on your reputation. But after a really careful reading, I have noticed the quoted paragraph: it's the 3rd one, in a not-so-obvious place. It is always better to include conclusions at the bottom. That's where we look for them.

Comment: Well, just removing that screwed-up special-processing if the scheme is not the canonical casing (aka lovercase) is an acceptable solution. Hope they deploy either this minimal-accepting or the maximum-accepting fix sometime soon...